# Adding a local system variable, or the result of a command, to a dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have seen some similar questions, but none of them appear to solve my problem. I want to add a user to a docker container and in my Dockerfile, I define the username with:

`ARG USERNAME="some_user"`

Instead, I want the username to be the current user's computer username, as obtained by running the command `whoami` in the local terminal.

So what I would like to have is something like

`ARG USERNAME=$(whoami)`
.

This $(whoami) should be obtained from the local system environment, and not from the docker container.
Is there a way to do this for dockerfiles? I have thought of `.env` and `docker-compose` solutions but these also require each user to set their own username according to my knowledge.

Comment: ...so if a different user wants to run your image, they need to rebuild it?  That's not usually a best practice; I'd try to design your image to be independent of the host system it runs on.  (Do not pass host usernames, user IDs, file paths, IP addresses, _etc._ into your image build, as a general rule.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no integrated way to execute arbitrary commands on the host directly *outside* of a container using just `docker build` / `docker-compose build`.

So to execute an arbitrary command to get/generate the required information you'll need to provide a custom script / use another build system to call `docker`/`docker-compose` with the respective flags or maybe generate the `.env` file from a template / interactively.

If you only need the current user name you may want to use the `$USER` / `$LOGNAME` environment variables that are set by the system in many default configurations. But since these are just normal environment variables their values may be incorrect / empty / manually changed by the user, see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/who-sets-user-and-username-environment-variables).